# Prove that for integers $a$ and $b$, the sequence $a, 2a, 3a,4a,5a,\dots, ba$ has $\gcd(a,b)$ multiples of $b$ in it.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for integers $a$ and $b$, the sequence $a, 2a, 3a,4a,5a,\dots, ba$ has $\gcd(a,b)$ multiples of $b$ in it.

I know:
Proof: Let $\gcd(a,b)=d$. Then $a=dm$ and $b=dn$.

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you please explain more what do you mean by "has $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ multiples of $b$ in it"? More precisely "$\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ multiples of $b$".

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj: it means that the number of multiples of $b$ in the sequence $(a,2a,\ldots,ba)$ is equal to $\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $b=dn$ and $a=dm$ then for $1\leq p\leq b\quad   b|pa$ if and only if $dn|pdm$ which means $n|pm$ thus $n|p$ hence, the multiples of b in the sequence are : na,2na,...,dna

Comment: Is p just a random integer?